# Determine MIME Content Type

Tags: c++, windows

I'm using C++ with a packet sniffer in Windows.  How do I get the Content Type of a MIME file that is about to be downloaded. I am new to this, so please don't delete my question. That will not help me to figure this out.  Ive been googling all day, and as far as I can see MIME content type is what I need but how and where do I access this file?

Answer (score 1):

The MIME type is sent as the `Content-Type` [HTTP header field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).  e.g. `Content-Type: image/jpeg`.  Note that HTTP headers are sent as plain text ahead of the actual content (payload).  They're not a separate file, as such.

Comment: Great news! So Im using a packet sniffer, I should be able to get this in the http header file. Correct?

Comment: @DSTR3: If your packet sniffer gives you visibility of the HTTP headers, then yes, you should.

Comment: I'm getting IP, TCP ICMP and UDP headers.  Is there a way to add HTTP headers?  Im in C++ / Windows. Thanks

Comment: @DSTR3: This will depend entirely on what features your packet sniffer offers.

Comment: I wrote it in C++ so I can add what I need to I suppose.  What do I need for HTTP?

Comment: @DSTR3: HTTP is a text-based protocol that rides on top of TCP (usually).  You will need to take TCP payloads, and parse their contents.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you so much, this explains a lot to me! I think I'm begining to understand this situation now.  I think I have to expand what I am getting from the TCP Sniff though.  I'm just getting Source IP, Destination IP, Sequence, and Flags I imagine that I need the data part as well, thenI parse that.